# How can I incorporate the css into a duplicated site?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to duplicate this site for a project I'm working on, but the HTML isn't recognizing the CSS in the programming, or some other similar issue. This is what I'm aiming for:

https://www.personalfinanceclub.com/the-cost-of-raising-a-child/

And this is what I have:

https://sunnyparks.github.io/personal-finance-club/FinalProject.html

Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates your problem, and also elaborate on the issue you're experiencing.  When I visit those two links, the pages look very nearly identical, so I think I may be missing something from your question

Answer (score 0):

Webfonts have been blocked by CORS policy.

**CORS Config for Apache**

To enable CORS in Apache, add the following to your `.htaccess` file.

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```